# Affect the datatable column value in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data Table as follows .

```
Name    Val  ID
--------------
Raja    0   101
---------------
Ram     0   102
---------------
Ray     0   103
---------------
Raja    0   104
---------------
```

I want to affect my datatable columns if same name repeats again.In my datatable the Raja name repeats Second time so i want to change the Name to Raja(2) .

O/p :

```
 Name   Val  ID
    --------------
    Raja    0   101
    ---------------
    Ram     0   102
    ---------------
    Ray     0   103
    ---------------
    Raja(2) 0   104
    ---------------
```

Please guide me to get this .

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(string));

            table.Rows.Add("AAA", "Indocin", "David");
            table.Rows.Add("XXX", "Enebrel", "Sam");
            table.Rows.Add("AAA", "Hydralazine", "Christoff");
            table.Rows.Add("CCC", "Combivent", "Janet");
            table.Rows.Add("AAA", "Dilantin", "Melanie");
           // Query with Linq
           var newNames = table.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select((row, rowIndex) => new { rowIndex, index }) // storing row and index of it in anonymous type
                                .GroupBy(x => x.row.Field<string>("Name"))          // group by Name
                                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)                          // take only duplicates
                                .SelectMany(g => g                                  // select all rows but first of duplicates
                                    .Where(x => x.rowIndex > 0)
                     /*Error*/               .Select((x, dupIndex) => new { x.rowIndex, newName = $"{g.Key}({dupIndex + 1})" }));    

            foreach(var x in newNames)
                table.Rows[x.index].SetField("Name", x.newName);
            /***********/
```

Here my code ..

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Linq-To-DataTable` especially `GroupBy`:

```
var newNames = table.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row, rowIndex) => new { row, rowIndex }) // storing row and index of it in anonymous type
    .GroupBy(x => x.row.Field<string>("Name"))          // group by Name
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)                          // take only duplicates
    .SelectMany(g => g                                  // select all rows but first of duplicates
        .Where(x => x.rowIndex > 0)
        .Select((x, dupIndex) => new { x.rowIndex, newName = $"{g.Key}({dupIndex + 2})" }));    

foreach(var x in newNames)
    table.Rows[x.rowIndex].SetField("Name", x.newName);
```

I'm grouping by name, then taking only rows(+ their index) which are duplicated. From those duplicate-groups i take all but the first(because that name remains).

Comment: Cod populates error in this line:.Select(x => new { x.index, newName = $"{g.Key}({x.index + 2})"}));

Comment: @Moni: i have edited my answer and added little explanation. Ask if you have further questions. It's tested

Comment: @ Tim .Select((x, dupIndex) => new { x.index, D = $"{g.Key}({dupIndex + 1})" }));    This line shows an error i cant able to use this ,please help me to fix

Comment: @Moni: since you dont mention the error i cant help you. As i told you, this is tested and works. So there must be something different for you(for example the framework or that you don't have added `using System.Linq;`). But i don't know if you dont even mention the error

Comment: Error:: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: @Moni: are you sure that you really use the same code that i'm using above? Maybe you have overlooked an edit. Because for me it compiles. What .NET version are you using?

Comment: Am using 4.5 .NET .But in that line only error occouring .

Comment: @moni: add the code that you have used to your question at the end and i will look